# IP Configuration (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

I have moved to a new server and was given a /29 IP block with it. I have never had more than one IP per server, so I am having a little trouble getting things sorted out and was wondering if I could get some help/advice.

Here is what I have assigned to me.

```
IP Block -> xxx.xxx.xxx.16/29
Subnet -> 255.255.255.248

Useable ->
     xxx.xxx.xxx.17 
     xxx.xxx.xxx.18
     xxx.xxx.xxx.19
     xxx.xxx.xxx.20
     xxx.xxx.xxx.21
     xxx.xxx.xxx.22
```

The server came came with the following setup.

```
/etc/hosts -> xxx.xxx.xxx.17
gateway -> xxx.xxx.xxx.17
address -> xxx.xxx.xxx.18
```

For some reason I could only SSH in on xxx.xxx.xxx.18 and could only ping xxx.xxx.xxx.17, is this normal for the gateway IP?

I am a little confused on what needs set to what. I have the following questions.

1. What address should I list in /etc/hosts and tie to my FQDN?
2. What address should I use for my gateway IP?
3. What is the best way to assign these IPs to one NIC? Are aliases still the way?

Comment: Do you even need more than one address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the gateway IP address that was assigned by the network administrator, otherwise you won't be able to reach the Internet. They will be able to tell you (usually it's the lowest numbered one, which here indeed is the one with 17 at the end).

As for what you use on your server, that's totally up to you! Any of the "usable" addresses that is not the gateway can be used, and will work. You can assign multiple IPs to your server if you want to, or you can bridge secondary IP addresses to VMs or containers, or some such. Go wild!

To assign more than one IP address to the same interface, you should *not* use aliases anymore; that way of doing things has been deprecated for ages. Instead, you should just assign multiple addresses to the same interface:

```
ip ad add xxx.xxx.xxx.17/29 dev eth0
ip ad add xxx.xxx.xxx.18/29 dev eth0
```

You may be able to configure that through your distribution's configuration system, but how to do that depends on the distribution in use.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I wasn’t necessarily asking what to use them for, more of which to assign to the gateway and such. Your response has been helpful!

Comment: The subnet broadcast address (`.23` in this instance) is also usually reserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these addresses in different ways. You can use a single IP for the host and do everything with that. You can use a dedicated IP for e.g. SSH and SNAT (for other systems in a cluster) and different services.

Have a look at

```
iptables -nvL
netstat --inet --inet6 -nl
```

for your current configuration.